# Spring Hibernate Configuration resulting in session NPE

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven-2

I'm having issues properly setting up my Hibernate configuration. After trying to extend the HibernateDaoSupport into a GenericDao and extending those to class-specific daos, but when I call findByNamedQuery in my dao, getSession() throws an NPE.

When I tried switching to extending HibernateTemplate, the hibernateTemplate doesn't get instantiated properly, and is still null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession(HibernateDaoSupport.java:143)
at com.jmt.hibernate.dao.GenericDaoImpl.findByNamedQuery(GenericDaoImpl.java)
```

What am I missing??

I used maven2 to build the project, 
1. added the hibernate plugin into my pom.xml:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>

    <configuration>
        <components>
            <component>
            <name>hb2ddl</name>
            <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
            </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
        <drop>true</drop>
        <outputfilename>output.sql</outputfilename>
        <format>false</format>
        <persistenceunit>MyEntityManager</persistenceunit>
        <ejb3>true</ejb3>
        </componentProperties>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2. defined my entity manager in persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

   <persistence-unit name="MyEntityManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> <!-- "JTA"> -->
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.jmt.model.UserEntity</class>

      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
      <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
      <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/><!-- org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url"  value="${jdbc.url}"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>

      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

3. wired up my daos in applicationContext.xml:

```
 <bean id="hibernateDaoSupport" abstract="true"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
    <bean id="hibernateHelper" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" >
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    <property name="hibernateManagedSession" value="true"/>
</bean>

    <bean class="com.jmt.model.UserEntity"/>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename"><value>messages</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="1000"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="60000"/>        
    </bean>   


    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">15</prop>   
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</prop>
            </props>       
        </property>
         <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.jmt.model</value>
                <value>com.jmt.hibernate.dao</value>
            </list>
        </property>        
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.jmt.hibernate.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg value="com.jmt.hibernate.dao.UserDaoImpl"/>
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

4. even added a filter into my web.xml hoping that would inject the session properly:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>sessionLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
```

I didn't add in a manager yet, hoping that fewer layers would make SOMETHING work...

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: @are you creating a new instance of GenericDaoImpl using new operator??

Comment: No, I expect Spring to manage that since my dao beans are declared at the bottom of my applicationContext.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck, I did not think about where the call to the dao was being made, and yes, that's why there wasn't an open session. Someone had used spring dwr to call the dao directly from a jsp file. Once I got rid of that and made the call from my Controller, the session was finally being instantiated properly. Thanks for the help, Japs!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to do openSession() rather doing getSession(). Because at that point there might be the case that your session is not opened and you are trying to get it and hence it will result in a NPE.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Hmm, so the following property in my transactionManager doesn't help with opening/closing hibernate sessions?
    <property name="hibernateManagedSession" value="true"/>

Comment: Well I don't know about that. But I'm sure that the problem occurred because trying to get the session before opening it. :-)